# Weak and unstable wifi

Tags: wifi, internet

I'm using EOS on a daily basis (with Win on dualboot) and I spend hours on skype for my job. The problem is my wifi signal is really unstable, even if I'm sitting at 3 meters from my internet box. I generally get around 100Mbps but Several time a day my internet reception go down to less than 1MBP. Btw, my box is sending around 600Mbps... 
When I go behind a wall, I get nothing at all... 
With windows, I don't have thos problems...

iwconfig :

```
enp1s0    no wireless extensions.

wlp2s0    IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"moimoimoi"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:5.56 GHz  Access Point: C6:B4:22:73:FD:9F   
          Bit Rate=433.3 Mb/s   Tx-Power=26 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=66/70  Signal level=-44 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:1754   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Answer (score 2):

not sure if this would help but try to boot from a usb using "try elementary" and install skype and check if this issue occured